# Ansible Skipping Task due to undefined error

Tags: ansible

Code Below Runs fine until it errors out on the Save locally task

```
 - local_action: file dest=firewallinfo.txt  state=touch

    - name: "Gather firewall information"
      script: firewall.sh
      register: output
    - debug: var=output

    - name: Firewall Name
      raw: hostname
      register: output2

    - debug: var=output2


    - name: the file
      raw: cat "{{item}}".csv
      with_items: '{{output2.stdout_lines}}'
      register: output3

    - debug: var=output3
```

This is where my code stops working. Anyone know why?

```
- name: save locally
  local_action: lineinfile dest=firewallinfo.txt  line="{{item}}"
  with_items: '{{output3.stdout_lines}}'
```

Comment: Do you get any output?

Comment: I get the debug of   - debug: var=output3 to work but when i try to take the stdout_lines of output3 and put into a file it gives me this error [DEPRECATION WARNING]: Skipping task due to undefined Error, in the future this will be a fatal error.. This feature will be removed in a future release. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting 
deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable `output3` is a result of muti-item task.
So `output3` is a dict with `results` list in it.
You need `output3.results[i].stdout_lines[j]`.

Change your task to:

```
- name: save locally
  local_action: lineinfile dest=firewallinfo.txt  line="{{item}}"
  with_items: "{{ output3.results | sum(attribute='stdout_lines', start=[]) | list }}"
```

It will combine all `stdout_lines` in every result and give you a flat list to iterate.